# CursorIndexOutofBoundexception in android

Tags: android

In following program code a `CursorIndexOutofBoundexception` is shown in the logcat while running the app. Pls give me a solution.

```
public String getContact(String datevalue,String Userselectvalue) {
        String selection = classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC + " = 'Userselectvalue'"  
                +" AND " + classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE + " = 'datevalue'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        Cursor cursor = db.query(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, 
                new String[] {classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT }, selection, 
                null, null, null, null);
             String  place = cursor.getString( );
        return place;
    }
```

Logcat :

```
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at example.showevent1.classdbOpenHelper.getContact(classdbOpenHelper.java:59)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at example.showevent1.FirstActivity$getclicker.onClick(FirstActivity.java:163)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-05 11:21:13.327: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getContact(String datevalue,String Userselectvalue) 
{
    String selection = classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC + " = 'Userselectvalue'"  
            +" AND " + classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE + " = 'datevalue'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    Cursor cursor = db.query(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, 
            new String[] {classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT }, selection, 
            null, null, null, null);
    String  place = null;

    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        place = cursor.getString(0);
    }

    return place;
}
```

The above should work.

The `0` in the `cursor.getString(0)` indicates the column number of the returned records (0 being the first column)

Consider cursors as dumb. You must specify the position in which they will start reading [ in the above example : First record ( `.moveToFirst()` ) and when they will skip to the next record ( `cursor.moveToNext()` )

You should definitely check the query though, LogCat is telling you that the cursor returned 0  records; `...with a size of 0`

Comment: Wouldn't work since the logcat says the size is 0 i.e. there are no result rows. Need to check the result of `moveToFirst()` to ensure there are results. Also, it's a good habit to `close()` your cursors after use.

Answer (score 1):

Before `cursor.getString()` you should put `cursor.moveToFirst()`

Actually you should put

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
 place = cursor.getString(**columnIndex**);
return place;
```

The cursor of your example is empty, so it's returning size 0 and the position is -1. That's why you should verify if it's empty with the `moveToFirst` call.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
 public String getContact(String datevalue,String Userselectvalue) 
 {
   String selection = classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC + " = 'Userselectvalue'"  
        +" AND " + classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE + " = 'datevalue'";
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
   Cursor cursor = db.query(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, 
        new String[] {classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT }, selection, 
        null, null, null, null);
   if (cursor .getCount() > 0) {
        cursor .moveToFirst();
        do {
             String  place = cursor.getString(0);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
 return place;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this.

```
public String getContact(String datevalue,String Userselectvalue) 
     {
       String selection = classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DESC + "=' + Userselectvalue + '"  
            +" AND " + classdbOpenHelper.KEY_DATE + " = ' + datevalue + '";
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
       Cursor cursor = db.query(classdbOpenHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, 
            new String[] {classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT }, selection, 
            null, null, null, null);
       if (cursor .getCount() > 0) {
            cursor .moveToFirst();
            do {
                 String  place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(classdbOpenHelper.KEY_EVENT));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
     return place; 
     }
```